# How to make Break even trigger more than one time in one entry

Tags: mql4

I now trying to make Break Even Code trigger more than one time,
example `EA` entry is 1.28000 and stop loss 1.28500
if current price reach 1.175000(50pips), `sl` move to break even such as to 1.28000(5pips).

`EA` will not make more modify order after condition are meet.

so how to trigger break even again if price reach 1.17000(100pips), sl move to (1.175000)(50 pips)

and again price reach 1.165000(150pips),sl move to 1.17000(100pips)

I want to make

```
BE_B_M(sl move to(example:5))
```

and

```
BE_B_T(price reach(example:50))
```

as variable and every time price reach target variable change to next value
so became

```
BE_B_M(sl move to(example:50)) and BE_B_T(price reach(example:100))
```

**The entire code is as follows**

```
extern double  BE_T_1      = 50;   
extern double  BE_M_1      = 5;  

extern double  BE_T_2      = 100;   
extern double  BE_M_2      = 50;

extern double  BE_T_3      = 150;   
extern double  BE_M_3      = 100;

double BE_S_M; 
double BE_S_T;

void MOVE_BE_1()

  {
   for(int b=OrdersTotal()-1;b>=0;b--)
     {

      if(OrderSelect(b,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES))
         if(OrderMagicNumber()!=M_Number)continue;
      if(OrderSymbol()==Symbol())
         if(OrderType()==OP_BUY)
            if(Bid-OrderOpenPrice()>BE_S_T*Pips)
               if(OrderOpenPrice()>OrderStopLoss())
                  if(!OrderModify(OrderTicket(),OrderOpenPrice(),OrderOpenPrice()+(BE_S_M*Pips),OrderTakeProfit(),0,CLR_NONE))
                     Print("eror");
     }

   for(int s=OrdersTotal()-1;s>=0;s--)
     {
      if(OrderSelect(s,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES))
         if(OrderMagicNumber()!=M_Number)continue;
      if(OrderSymbol()==Symbol())
         if(OrderType()==OP_SELL)
            if(OrderOpenPrice()-Ask>BE_S_T*Pips)
               if(OrderOpenPrice()<OrderStopLoss())
                  if(!OrderModify(OrderTicket(),OrderOpenPrice(),OrderOpenPrice()-(BE_S_M*Pips),OrderTakeProfit(),0,CLR_NONE))
                     Print("eror");
     }

  }
```

i expect sl will move after price reach every 50pips from entry

Comment: What is "1.28000(5pips)." in your message? What you are asking for is called trailing stop not breakeven. Do you need to have different values for BE and trailing stop/step or it should be always 50 pips difference?

Comment: It first break even. It a default set. Stoploss(SL) will go 5pips above entry if current price is 50pis above from entry price. Yes i want to have different value for BE.

Comment: My mistake. 1.28050 it correct value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can put all the 3 break even levels on one function.

Note: you can use 1 `for-loop` for both `OP_BUY` and `OP_SELL`

Here is my `OnInit()`

```
// Global variable
double point;

int OnInit()
  {
   if(Digits == 5 || Digits == 3) point=Point*10;
   else point=Point;
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
  }
```

Here is the `BreakEven()` function

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Break even the trade at 3  levels                                |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void BreakEven()
  {
   // get the stop level for that symbol
   double stopLevel = SymbolInfoInteger(Symbol(),SYMBOL_TRADE_STOPS_LEVEL)*Point;

   for(int i=OrdersTotal()-1;i>=0;i--)
     {
      if(!OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES)) continue;
      if(OrderMagicNumber()!=M_Number)continue;
      if(OrderSymbol()!=Symbol())continue;

      if(OrderType()==OP_BUY)
        {
         double profitPips=Bid-OrderOpenPrice();
         double newSL=OrderStopLoss();

         if(profitPips>=BE_T_1*point && OrderStopLoss()<OrderOpenPrice()) // Break Even
           {
            newSL=OrderOpenPrice()+BE_M_1*point;
           }
         else if(profitPips>=BE_T_3*point) // 150/100
           {
            newSL=OrderOpenPrice()+BE_M_3*point;
           }
         else if(profitPips>=BE_T_2*point) // 100/50
           {
            newSL=OrderOpenPrice()+BE_M_2*point;
           }

         if(newSL>=OrderStopLoss()+Point && newSL<Bid-stopLevel)
            if(!OrderModify(OrderTicket(),OrderOpenPrice(),NormalizeDouble(newSL,Digits),OrderTakeProfit(),0))
               Print("Error at BE: ",GetLastError());
        }
      else if(OrderType()==OP_SELL)
        {
         double profitPips=OrderOpenPrice()-Ask;
         double newSL=OrderStopLoss();
         if(profitPips>=BE_T_1*point && (OrderStopLoss()>OrderOpenPrice() || OrderStopLoss()==0)) // Break Even
           {
            newSL=OrderOpenPrice()-BE_M_1*point;
           }
         else if(profitPips>=BE_T_3*point) // 150/100
           {
            newSL=OrderOpenPrice()-BE_M_3*point;
           }
         else if(profitPips>=BE_T_2*point) // 100/50
           {
            newSL=OrderOpenPrice()-BE_M_2*point;
           }

         if(newSL<=OrderStopLoss()-Point && newSL>Ask+stopLevel)
            if(!OrderModify(OrderTicket(),OrderOpenPrice(),NormalizeDouble(newSL,Digits),OrderTakeProfit(),0))
               Print("Error at BE: ",GetLastError());
        }
     }

  }
```

I didn't test this myself in a trade, but it should work.